# 2d Array loop display

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, for-loop

I have this excerise to do where I need to create two arrays like this:

```
arrayA[2][3];
arrayB[2][3];
```

and a third array to store the result of 1[2][3] + 2[2][3]. I need to use a double loop and a double loop only to iterate over the elements in the arrays, compute the sum of each compenent and store it in the third array. Finally I have to output the third arrays sum.

The progam needs to look like this:

```
A =
-5 2 8
1 0 0 

B =
1 0 2
0 3 -6  

A + B =
-4 2 10
1 3 -6
```

However I can't get it  to work with two arrays in a double for loop only, nothing more. Here's what I've done. I've only come so far and when I try to add another array in the "j loop" everything gets messed up. Is this possible to do with only a double loop without the use of functions and stuff like that (im only supposed to use loops and logical conditions in this chapter):

```
int matrixA[2][3] = 
{
    {-5, 2, 8}, 
    {1, 0, 0}
};

int matrixB[2][3] =
{
    {1, 0, 2}, 
    {0, 3, -6}
};

int matrixC[2][3];

for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; ++j)
    {   
        cout << matrixA[i][j] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Like I said it works fine if I either only display one arrays data or use more loops however I only have to use a double for-loop and nothing else. On top of that I have no idea how to get another space between 1 0 0 and B = and how to add A =, B= and A + B = in this loop.

**EDIT:** @Niklas, thanks for the answer but I really don't understand how to 'prepare' an output. According to my assignment I need to use, and I'm quoting the text "a double for-loop to iterate over the matrix elements, compute the sum of each component and store the result in the third matrix. Finally output the matrix sum." Will add this to OP as well.

Comment: To address your edit describing the problem you have been given: The first part of my answer does exactly this. You only need to output **one** matrix, the sum matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can gather, your main aim is to add the two matrices (represented by 2D arrays) together and store the result in `matrixC`, while also outputting it. It seems you are on the right track, only minor modification is required to achieve this.

The following modification to your code should do the trick (only 2 for loops are used):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; ++j)
    {   
        matrixC[i][j] = matrixA[i][j] + matrixB[i][j];
        cout << matrixC[i][j] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

That should add the corresponding cells of `matrixA` and `matrixB` together and store the result in `matrixC`. It will also be outputted.

---

**EDIT:** In light of new information (your comment under this answer), it seems you need to output more than one of these matrices, but still with only two `for` loops. The solution is simple: create a function that outputs a matrix, and use it whenever you need to output one:

```
void outputMatrix( int mtx[2][3] )
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; ++j)
        {   
            cout << mtx[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Now if you need to output `matrixA` then `matrixB` then `matrixC`, just do this:

```
outputMatrix( matrixA );
outputMatrix( matrixB );
outputMatrix( matrixC );
```

This code isn't really generic though, since it relies on a fixed 2x3 array size. But I'm trying to keep things simple for you.

---

**EDIT2:** A solution without functions:

Create 3 `std::stringstream`s, one for each matrix. Instead of outputting everything at once, we'll buffer each matrix output separately, then output each one consecutively.

```
std::stringstream mtxAOut, mtxBOut, mtxCOut;
for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; ++j)
    {   
        matrixC[i][j] = matrixA[i][j] + matrixB[i][j];
        mtxAOut << matrixA[i][j] << " ";
        mtxBOut << matrixB[i][j] << " ";
        mtxCOut << matrixC[i][j] << " ";
    }
    mtxAOut << endl;
    mtxBOut << endl;
    mtxCOut << endl;
}
// Now output...
cout << mtxAOut.str() << endl << mtxBOut.str() << endl << mtxCOut.str();
```

I don't know what you've learned or not, there are many ways to approach this problem and your instructor is probably a better bet for advice here - especially if you are supposed to use a particular technique.

Comment: Sorry, I should've mentioned I need to first display A, then B, then adding them and displaying C. All text should be formatted like I showed in the first code box.

Comment: Haven't gone over functions so the excerise should be solved without it.

Comment: Guess I should've been more clearer. This is what I've learned so far (very basic stuff)

* different variables
* type conversions
* declarations and definitions
* if & else
* switch
* for, while, do, break, continue and nesting loops
* array anad multidimensional arrays

-- this is all I've learned so far.

Comment: The thing is, according to your task description (the recent edit in your question), the first part of my answer already solves your problem. You only need to output the **matrix sum**. What is it that you still need to do? You've only been taught basic stuff it seems, I think you're looking too deeply into the assignment.

Comment: I do not think I do. Every assignment got a picture on exactly how it should look. Here's the picture for this one: http://i.imgur.com/lw1tU.png

Comment: Well you can always hardcode the output of the first two matrices like so: `cout << "A = \n -5 2 8 \n 1 0 0";` ...etc

Comment: It IS bad practice in reality, hardcoding values should be avoided where possible (although in *beginning* C++ courses it is generally an acceptable practice for the sake of simplicity). If I were you, I'd ask your instructor what to do. I think the image is misleading to be honest, the instructions themselves only mention outputting the sum matrix. I feel that the *main thing* your instructor is interested in, is that you're able to add the two matrices together and output the FINAL one, not the first two.

Answer (score 0):

Do as Alex Z's solution for calculation and to display, and as this sounds as homework, do the following in code:

**Prepare the output in advance for each matrix and print it when complete.**

Comment: thanks for the answer but I really don't understand how to 'prepare' an output. According to my assignment I need to use, and I'm quoting the text "a double for-loop to iterate over the matrix elements, compute the sum of each component and store the result in the third matrix. Finally output the matrix sum." Will add this to OP as well.

Comment: Well, I was kind of evil to avoid giving you the solution. As it is a homework, I wanted to give you a clue.